# "No module named pandas" error on visual studio code - NO ISSUE on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I recently installed anaconda and was using jupyter notebook to write my code. I also installed Visual Studio code and ran my jupyter files (.ipynb) in VSC.

Whenever I try to import pandas in VSC within a jupyter file (.ipynb), I get an error that says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'`. However, when I run the same file in Chrome on the Jupyter notebook website, I get no such error and my file is able to import pandas.

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Please read [ask], as a preliminary. How did you install Pandas? Do you know how to check what Python installations are on your system, and how to check which one is running? When you use VSC to run the file, which Python installation is running? You *do* understand that, when you use "the jupyter notebook website", the code will run *on the Jupyter servers*, not involving your Anaconda installation at all, right?

Comment: Please note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. Rather than pre-emptively apologizing for anything, do your best to ask according to the site standards. We will fix what we can (within site policy), and politely ask you to fix anything that needs your [edit]ing input.

Comment: Also: what tutorial are you using to learn Python? If you are new to programming in general or Python in particular, you should be focusing on the fundamentals, and not trying to use more sophisticated libraries such as Pandas.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are working on a different environment and the error is occurring because pandas module is in different path try installing pandas in your current environment and importing it might work

This might help..
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that when you open an .ipynb file in jupyter-notebook, it is running in a conda environment with pandas installed. And it is running on VSC in a Windows or OS environment, which may not have pandas installed.
On cmd run, pip install pandas then import it on VSC.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the above comments. On cmd run (pip show pandas), it actually showed pandas was installed.

However, the reason was because the selected interpreter was a non-conda version, which can be changed in the top right of VCS. Hope this helps anyone who has a similar issue!